# Magento 2 Missing Wishlist Tables

Tags: magento2, database

I am working with a Magento 2 database that is missing the 3 wishlist tables.

```
wishlist
wishlist_item       
wishlist_item_option
```

Is there a mysql script I can run to create these tables?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had same issue 2.3.5 after setting 'Magento_Wishlist' => 0, and setup:upgrade
these tables got deleted.

> CREATE TABLE `wishlist` (   `wishlist_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
> AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Wishlist ID',   `customer_id` int(10) unsigned
> NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Customer ID',   `shared` smallint(5)
> unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Sharing flag (0 or 1)',
> `sharing_code` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Sharing encrypted
> code',   `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Last
> updated date',   PRIMARY KEY (`wishlist_id`),   UNIQUE KEY
> `WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID` (`customer_id`),   KEY `WISHLIST_SHARED`
> (`shared`),   CONSTRAINT
> `WISHLIST_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY
> (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE
> CASCADE ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
> COMMENT='Wishlist main Table';

NEXT:

> CREATE TABLE `wishlist_item` (   `wishlist_item_id` int(10) unsigned
> NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Wishlist item ID',   `wishlist_id`
> int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Wishlist ID',
> `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Product
> ID',   `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store
> ID',   `added_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Add date and
> time',   `description` text COMMENT 'Short description of wish list
> item',   `qty` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Qty',   PRIMARY KEY
> (`wishlist_item_id`),   KEY `WISHLIST_ITEM_WISHLIST_ID`
> (`wishlist_id`),   KEY `WISHLIST_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`),
> KEY `WISHLIST_ITEM_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),   CONSTRAINT
> `WISHLIST_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN
> KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`)
> ON DELETE CASCADE,   CONSTRAINT
> `WISHLIST_ITEM_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`)
> REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,   CONSTRAINT
> `WISHLIST_ITEM_WISHLIST_ID_WISHLIST_WISHLIST_ID` FOREIGN KEY
> (`wishlist_id`) REFERENCES `wishlist` (`wishlist_id`) ON DELETE
> CASCADE ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Wishlist items';

NEXT:

> CREATE TABLE `wishlist_item_option` (
> `option_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Option ID',
> `wishlist_item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Wishlist Item ID',
> `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Product ID',
> `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Code',
> `value` text COMMENT 'Value',
> PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`),
> KEY `FK_A014B30B04B72DD0EAB3EECD779728D6` (`wishlist_item_id`),
> CONSTRAINT `FK_A014B30B04B72DD0EAB3EECD779728D6` FOREIGN KEY (`wishlist_item_id`) REFERENCES `wishlist_item` (`wishlist_item_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Wishlist Item Option Table';

Problem sorted!